# How can I create an empty DB for testing?

Tags: prisma

I'm writing some integration tests for my RESTful API that uses Prisma within.

As part of those tests I'd like to work with a DB that has a known state - an empty one is simplest.

AFAICS The JavaScript/TypeScript API lacks an equivalent of `npx prisma db push --force-reset`. How does the community recommend I tackle this requirement in code, w/o creating a child process?

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't using `npx prisma migrate reset --force` work in your case?

https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/command-reference#migrate-reset

Comment: I've clarified my post - I'm looking for something in the JS Prisma API  I can call directly from within Node, w/o creating a child process to run `npx something something`.